# Error creating scratch orgs

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org

While creating a scratch org i get the following error.

```
ERROR running force:org:create:  Socket timeout occurred while listening for results. 

Try this: 
Use command "sfdx force:data:soql:query -q "SELECT Status FROM ScratchOrgInfo WHERE Id='2SR1n000000L1XcGAK'"" to retry. You may consider increasing --wait parameter value to increase timeout.
11:13:58.529 sfdx force:org:create -f config/project-scratch-def.json --setalias test --durationdays 7 --setdefaultusername ended with exit code 1
```

If i visit the record Id provided in the Devhub the ScratchOrg has a status New and  the ScratchOrgId is empty.

Somehow it doesn't become active.

[image]

How can I investigate what is going wrong and is there a way I can fix this?

Comment: Are you working under a client network having corporate firewall? [Error message](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G000000BiJEQA0) in this post seems related.

Comment: No firewall. If I use a devhub with the trailhead examples I don't have this issue.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the permission set for using our Devhub was not properly configured. A permission set should at least have the following: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_add_users.htm